# How To Empty a Dynamic Array

Tags: performance, delphi, dynamic-arrays, freepascal

I need to re-use a dynamic arrays many times as I consider it a better performance.
Hence, I don't need to create a new dynamic array every time I need it.

I want to ask if it can lead to bugs and inefficiency if I use the same array for several instructions then clear it and reuse it? And how can I correct my procedure, so, it might approach my need.
My code :

```
procedure Empty(local_array : array of Integer);
var
    i : Integer;

begin
    for i:= 0 to high(local_array) do 
        local_array[i]:= nil;
        Setlength(local_array, 0);          
end;
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile.

Comment: Your proposed solution is a bit flawed. 1) The `local_array` is passed by value, which means it's a copy of the original array. 2) You should set the array values to zero, not nil. 3) The last thing you do is to set the length of the array to zero, which contradicts your objective to reuse the array for performance reasons.

Comment: If you want to reuse an array, you should reuse it. Your code, once it compiles, doesn't do that. It destroys the array. I'm pretty sure you are trying to optimise for performance without really understanding how dynamic arrays are implemented. You need that understanding before you can address performance.

Comment: Also worth pointing out that the code in the question doesn't even have a dynamic array. That an open array.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's right I don't have the full knowledge, I just started dealing with dynamic arrays and trying to manage them in the best way. I have posted this question for the simple reason, that i wasn't able to find a away to reuse a defined array in more than a situation, once I need it, I clear the old memory and reuse it. Or in case I don't need it anymore, so I destroy it so it doesn't fill a useless virtual memory. Thank you for your kind answer.

Comment: The documentation is a great place to begin with: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays, http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Internal_Data_Formats_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Array_Types, http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Open_Array_Parameters, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reuse your array don't mes with its size. Changing the size of an array or more specifically increasing it is what could lead to the need for data reallocation.

What is array data reallocation?
In Delphi all arrays need to be stored in continuous memory block. This means that if you are trying to increase the size of your array and there already some data after memory block that is currently assigned to your array the whole array needs to be moved to another memory location where there is enough space to store the new array size in one continuous memory block.

So instead of resizing your array leave its size alone and just set value of array items to some default value. Yes this means that such array will still occupy its allocated memory. But that is goal of reusing such array as you avoid overhead for allocating/deallocating memory to your array.

If you go this way don't forget to store your own count of used items in your array since its length may be larger than the number of item actually used.